# Can't find .unison directory on Mac OSX Sierra

Tags: macos, unison

I installed Unison via MacPorts on Mac OSX Sierra. I've read some tutorials online, and now want to write my own profile to set up the synchronization. Sadly, I can't find the `.unison` folder where the profiles are stored in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly certain that you have to make your own `.unison` directory and profiles. The `.unison` directory should be in the home directory, so `mkdir ~/.unison`. Otherwise, the default path of the directory is stored in the `UNISON` environment variable. See [this entry in the Unison manual](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html#unisondir) for more info. And then see the [Unison tag wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unison/info) for some sample profiles.

Answer (score 12):

Profiles and archive files are stored in folder `~/Library/Application Support/Unison`.